# Invoke-Expression in foreach

Tags: powershell

```
$test1 = {Get-Process}
$test2 = {Get-Process}
$test3 = {Get-Process}
```

I want to execute an Invoke-Command automatically in a foreach.

I tried the following but not working :

```
1..3 | %{& ($("`$test$_"))}
1..3 | %{Invoke-Command "`$test$_"}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit untidy because you need to run an `invoke-expression` (`iex`) to evaluate the variables first:

```
 1..3 | % { invoke-command $(iex "`$test$_") }
```

I'd recommend just putting the commands directly into an array and iterating over that instead:

```
$cmds = @({Get-Process},{Get-Process},{Get-Process})
$cmds | % { Invoke-Command $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks! What the difference between Invoke-Command and Invoke-Expression?

Comment: In short, `Invoke-Expression` evaluates commands to be run on the local computer. `Invoke-Command` requires PSRemoting to be enabled and can be run locally or on remote machines. Read `Get-Help Invoke-Expression` / `Get-Help Invoke-Command` for more

Answer (score 1):

That would be a lot cleaner using Get-Variable:

```
$test1 = {Get-Process}
$test2 = {Get-Process}
$test3 = {Get-Process}

1..3 | foreach { .(Get-Variable test$_).value}
```